# SQLite SELECT not displaying in Ruby console?

Tags: sql, ruby, sqlite

When I run this code:

```
require 'sqlite3'
db = SQLite3::Database.new ":memory:"
  db.execute 'CREATE TABLE foo (bar TEXT);'
  db.execute 'INSERT INTO foo VALUES ("baz");'
  db.execute 'SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar="baz"'
db.close
```

I get nothing. Normally in SQLite when I run:

```
create table foo (bar TEXT);
insert into foo values ("baz");
select * from foo;
```

I get:

```
bar       
----------
baz
```

Why does this happen and how can I get the exact same result?

Comment: I'd recommend looking at the [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/) gem. It's a great tool that will help abstract your code making it a lot easier to talk to SQLite, or other DBMs, without requiring database-specific changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`SQLite3::Database#execute`](http://sqlite-ruby.rubyforge.org/sqlite3/classes/SQLite3/Database.html#M000103) method does not print the result. Print the record explicitly.

```
require 'sqlite3'
db = SQLite3::Database.new ":memory:"
db.execute 'CREATE TABLE foo (bar TEXT);'
db.execute 'INSERT INTO foo VALUES ("baz");'
db.execute 'SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar="baz"' do |row| # <----
  p row                                                 # <----
end                                                     # <----
db.close
```